# TSQL Get Inserted Ids

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This question has been asked before...but I can't seem to find the exact answer I'm looking for... I need to insert a bunch of records and get back the inserted identity values... I'm doing this:

```
INSERT MyTable(col1, ....)
OUTPUT inserted.IdentityColumn
SELECT p.i.value('@XmlAttribute', 'nvarchar(128)') FROM @myXml.nodes('/root/i') AS p(i)
```

This works fine...

Enter SQL transactional replication with updatable subscriptions, which places triggers on replicated tables on subscribers.

OUTPUT no longer works in this scenario...

So, I'm doing this now...but I have a bad feeling in my gut about this and I think I've opened the door to a concurrency issue (though I'm not positive).

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE  
DECLARE @currentIdentity bigint
SET @currentIdentity = SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('MyTable') + 1
...
SELECT IdentityColumn FROM MyTable WHERE IdentityColumn <= IDENT_CURRENT('MyTable') AND IdentityColumn >= @currentIdentity
```

Suggestions? This also stinks because the approach doesn't work for generated uniqueidentifiers.

Comment: Why doesn't your first statement work with replication?  Seems like it's the second one that would be questionable with replication because of ID partitioning.

Comment: Can't use OUTPUT syntax if there are any triggers on the table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the variant of `OUTPUT` that inserts into a table variable. From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms177564.aspx):

> If the OUTPUT clause is specified **without also specifying the INTO keyword**, the target of the DML operation cannot have any enabled trigger defined on it for the given DML action. For example, if the OUTPUT clause is defined in an UPDATE statement, the target table cannot have any enabled UPDATE triggers.

(**Emphasis** added)

So, you can have:

```
DECLARE @IDs table (ID int not null)
INSERT MyTable(col1, ....)
OUTPUT inserted.IdentityColumn INTO @IDs
SELECT p.i.value('@XmlAttribute', 'nvarchar(128)') FROM @myXml.nodes('/root/i') AS p(i)

SELECT * from @IDs
```

Which will have approximately the same behaviour as the original, unless you're processing e.g. row count messages.

Comment: But then I can't get an identity value back...no?

Comment: @JeffN825 - I'm not sure what you're asking. If your first query (using `OUTPUT` without `INTO`) produces your desired result set, then the query I've shown (modified to include `INTO`) should produce exactly the same result. Except it works even if the table has triggers defined on it, which was what you said the problem was.